# Bad Google Places Data

Tags: android, ios, google-places

I'm using the `autocompleteQuery` endpoint in `address` filter mode in my app to let users search for places.  When they select a place, I'm calling the `lookUpPlaceID` endpoint to get details of that place, and then parsing the returned address components to try and extract a street number + name.  I've come across some weirdness that doesn't seem reportable through the normal channels:

google place id ChIJUcZ-NbzMj4ARC4FFj9ogS3s is “San José City Hall”…it has an address set, but does not show up when I search with the “address” filter.

google place id ChIJm-FhNrzMj4ARvjjHMCiJdM8 is “San Jose City Hall”…it *doesn’t* have an address, but *does* show up when I search with the “address” filter.

I can't use their "edit this place" tool because it doesn't recognize ChIJm-FhNrzMj4ARvjjHMCiJdM8 as actually being a Place.  This basically seems like a bug in Google Places but I can't find anywhere to report a bug :/  Mostly just posting here in case somebody can spot something wrong I'm doing:

```
func doSearch() {
  let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
  filter.type = .address
  GMSPlacesClient.shared().autocompleteQuery("San Jose City Hall", bounds: bound, filter: filter, callback: { results, error in ... }
}

func onResultSelected(_ result: GMSAutocompletePrediction) {
  GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPlaceID(result.placeID, callback: { result, error in ... }
}
```

Comment: Of note: the bogus place entries seem to be of type "premise".  ChIJ35EqNL1S8DURjjSMed825XU is another example

Comment: Apparently bugs for the places API are just supposed to be filed on issuetracker.google.com, so I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79666103